# Scale constrols inside TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

Why `tableLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` do not work and `tableLayoutPanel` does not fill all available space in `Form`?

How to scale `button.Text = "Button";`?

```
namespace Scalability
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            ViewForm viewForm = new ViewForm();
            Application.Run(viewForm);
        }
    }
}

namespace Scalability.Forms
{
    class ViewForm:Form
    {
        public ViewForm()
        {
            TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "Button";
            button.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text="Label";
            label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Text = "textBox";
            textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button, 0, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(label, 0, 1);
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(textBox, 1, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            this.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you suspect your code? Try to make form in designer and if it behave correctly - compare code to generated one in the `InitializeComponents()`. Otherwise we need a picture to see what "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

configurate `RowStyles` of `TableLayoutPanel` to make them stretch

```
TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
```

Answer (score 0):

But it does work. :)

1) Try to attach colors to your controls like this.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Text = "Button";
button.BackColor = Color.Orange;
button.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Label";
label.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Text = "textBox";
textBox.BackColor = Color.Green;
textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Now you will see that the controls use your entire window exactly in the way you put them. So button is col 0, row 0 (left, top). Textbox is col 1, row 0 (right, top). Label is col 0, row 1 (left bottom). And there is nothing in col 1 row 1 (right bottom "central place" is empty).

If you add a button to 1,1 it will stretch in the remaining space. Like this

```
// Blue button.
Button bbutton = new Button();
bbutton.Text = "Button";
bbutton.BackColor = Color.Blue;
bbutton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button, 0, 0);
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(label, 0, 1);
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(textBox, 1, 0);
// We added this one.
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(bbutton, 1, 1);
tableLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

So there you have it.